# Get Namespace from InvocationExpressionSyntax in Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, analyzer

I'm attempting to create an Analyzer for Roslyn that will prevent the use of Asserts within a given namespace (to ensure that the project design standard is maintained).

I've been able to get to the point where I can verify if this is an assert, but I am unsure how get the namespace from the context.

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeMethod, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
}

private static void AnalyzeMethod(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var expression = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

    var memberAccessExpression = expression.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

    if (memberAccessExpression == null) return;

    var memberSymbol = ModelExtensions.GetSymbolInfo(context.SemanticModel, memberAccessExpression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

    if (!memberSymbol?.ToString().Contains("Assert") ?? true) return;

    //Check if we're inside the Page Namespace.


    //This is an Assert, lets fail it.
    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, memberAccessExpression.GetLocation(), memberAccessExpression.Name);

    context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
}
```

When inspecting the `context` object itself, I can see a `ContainingSymbol` object, that contains a `ContainingNamespace` property, but when I try to code against this, I don't appear to be able to access it.

[image: ContainingNamespace]

Whats the easiest method of getting the class namespace? i.e. I want the namespace of the class the `Assert` is *in*, not the namespace of the `assert`.

As a bonus question - Is there any decent documentation on any of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have pulled down the latest packages via NuGet.

However I don't understand why you are able to see it at runtime using the debugger but unable to code against it.

Comment: This was the winner. Seems strange that you can see it at runtime, but need the updated packages to be able to see it.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix: If you're running in VS, you're using the latest packages at runtime regardless, due to VS bindingRedirects.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks. So what happens if I code for the latest version and someone tries to use the package on an older VS2015 Update? Is it likely to break?

Answer (score 2):

`ContainingSymbol` returns the base `ISymbol` interface, which can represent *any* symbol.

To access more-specific properties, you need to cast it to a more-specific interface, such as `IMethodSymbol`.

Comment: So part of the issue is that I can't even see the containingsymbol property on the context. How do I get to it?

Comment: That should work.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalysisContext.cs,1110